# How do I resolve fatal error message from phpmyadmin via Xampp?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I get the following error message whenever i tried to access phpmyadmin via xampp localhost

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Plugins\AuthenticationPlugin.php:257 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Plugins\AuthenticationPlugin.php(85): PhpMyAdmin\Plugins\AuthenticationPlugin->setSessionAccessTime() #1 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Plugins\AuthenticationPlugin.php(279): PhpMyAdmin\Plugins\AuthenticationPlugin->storeCredentials() #2 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\common.inc.php(263): PhpMyAdmin\Plugins\AuthenticationPlugin->authenticate() #3 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\index.php(15): require_once('C:\xampp\phpMyA...') #4 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Plugins\AuthenticationPlugin.php on line 257

Comment: This is an issue with the phpmyadmin product, you need to raise it on their support forum.

Comment: When you get an error message, start by searching on it. When searched for the error and "phpmyadmin", I found several questions and answers about this exact error online.